# unable to scrap tweets using from twitter using selenium and bs4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, twitter

I am beginner in selenium and web scraping.
I wrote this code to scrap and print tweets from twitter page of NASA but this is not printing all the tweets that were available in the webpage.
some help or advice would be much appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://twitter.com/nasa'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
pagesource = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource,'lxml')
tweets = soup.find_all('div',class_='css-901oao r-1nao33i r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0')
for tweet in tweets :
    print(tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found there is one sample project for get one's twitter text list, maybe you can refer it on [github](https://github.com/automation9417/automation-samples/tree/main/ScrapingPeopleRecentTweets)